# Поиск по datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Здравствуйте помогите исправить код,для поиска строки во втором стобце `datagridview`.Есть такой код

```
 for (int i = Weapon_grid.CurrentRow.Index+1; i < Weapon_grid.RowCount; i++)
            {
                Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Search_textbox.Text) && Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Search_textbox.Text.ToLower()))
                {

                            Weapon_grid.CurrentCell = Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Cells[0];
                            break;
                }
                else if (!Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Search_textbox.Text.ToLower()))
                {

                    if (i == Weapon_grid.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Совпадений не найдено");
                        Weapon_grid.CurrentCell = Weapon_grid.Rows[0].Cells[2];
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        {
                    continue;
                    }
                }
```

В первом цикле используется `Weapon_grid.CurrentRow.Index+1` для того что бы продолжить поиск с определенной строки а не начинать заново,так же может быть несколько одинаковых значений.
он работает,но его проболема в том что он выделает нужную мне строку только после второго нажатия на button.
Тоесть к пример я ищу значение "Test"в `datagridview`.
У меня допустим в стобце есть таких 4 значения это :**"Test1"**,**"Test2"**,**"Test3"**,**"Test4"**.
Когда начинаю поиск он выделит Test1 но не начнет передавать его значения по индексу в `textbox`.Когда нажимаю второй раз на кнопку то он выделяет Test2 но в `textbox` передает значения Test1.
Заполнение происходит полученим данных из бинарного файла в `List<>`.

```
 for(int i=0;i<rf.Third_amount;i++)
        {
            Weapon_grid.Rows.Add(i+1,rf.Struct[i].Id, rf.Struct[i].Name);
        }
```

`rf` это экземпляр класса,`struct` это коллекция `list`.
Прошу помочь исправить ошибку в первом коде.

Comment: У тебя небось, к DataGrid подвязан какой-то лист. Не проще ли искать в нем? Код бы был бы более изящный. Удаляешь объекты из BindingList(Типа скрываешь) и переносишь их в новый временный List. Когда приходит время открытия, переносишь их назад в подвязанный List.

Answer (score 1):

Я могу ошибаться , но разве не тут ошибка ?

```
Weapon_grid.CurrentCell = Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Cells[0];<----
```

В последнем индексе должно быть 2 т.е. Cells[2]. Т.к. у вас выше идет проверка значения именно с Cells[2] `Weapon_grid.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Search_textbox.Text.ToLower()))`

Comment: СКорее всего нет.Ошибки в коде и не было просто когда выделялись строка (у меня стоит fullrowselect)индекс почему то не передавался в datagridview_selection changed.